# Is there a way to superimpose an image on a person in relatime?

Tags: image-processing, flutter, dart

I am trying to create an e-commerce application where the user can select the cloth he/she wants to try and the camera opens up pointed towards the user and he/she can see the cloth on him/herself. How does it look and fits all in realtime. Is there a way to do so ?

Till now i have done pose estimation in the app following the below article
https://medium.com/flutter-community/posenet-for-ios-android-and-flutter-using-tensorflow-lite-836788a110c7

Answer (score 0):

With the help of TensoFlow LITE we can detect person in realtime using flutter camera,

YOLO model is used for person recogination by using tensorFlow,

Please follow the below guidelines
https://blog.francium.tech/real-time-object-detection-on-mobile-with-flutter-tensorflow-lite-and-yolo-android-part-a0042c9b62c6